# Feedback: Mobile Development Course Outline

Tags: curriculum-review, app-development

What do you think about the following course outline for the course "**Mobile App Development**"? I'm doing Compose, only last few lectures are reserved for XML layouts.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OWIkcwJ8OpKFy0Kz7PW91HnrEmiuEgBa9PrNCElED8k/edit?usp=sharing

Do you think any topic is missing? or any present topic should be replaced? Detailed feedback is appreciated.